# Why this function should be called by reference?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I have a piece of code like this(implementing Tree)

```
struct Node
{
   int val;
   struct node* left,*right;
   Node(int x){
     val=x;
     left=right=NULL;
   }
};

void insert(Node* &h,int val){
  if(h==NULL){
    h=new Node(val);
    return; 
  }
  if(h->val > val){
    insert(h->left,val);
  }
  else {
     insert(h->right,val);
  }
} 

void temp(Node* h,int val){        // Node* h doesn't seem to work but
                                   // Node*& h does!!!
     insert(h,val);
}

int main() {

struct Node* R=NULL;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  cin>>x;
  temp(R,x);
}
  return 0; 
}
```

Please ignore minor mistakes and other formal including of library(this code not for compilation).

**My question is** :-  Why the address need to be passed by reference in the line mentioned ?

**My point**:I am sending address of Root from the main to temp function and then the temp function is sending that address to the insert function by **Reference** to insert function which is changing it by permanently so why not address of root changing here ? And if it is an error than which address is actually changing here ?

Comment: "pass by reference" means that the function can change the original value.  Otherwise it can't.

Comment: is `traverse` supposed to be `temp`

Comment: @M.M Sorry about that.Edited!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, otherwise the parameter will be passed by value. So, main's `R`, or whatever is the root node of the tree, will then remain completely unchanged after `temp()`/`insert()` returns.

If it was initially `NULL`, it will still be `NULL` after `temp()` returns, even, supposedly a new node was inserted as the root node. All that happened is the value copy of the parameter was updated, instead of the real root node, leaking memory.

Comment: But what about passing by reference parameter in insert funcion!!! I am passing by reference there.What is it changing then ?

Comment: It's changing the `h` value in temp(). That's what it's a reference to. It's not changing the `R` value in main(), because it was passed by value to temp(), and `h` parameter in temp() is passed by reference to insert(), so insert() changes temp()'s parameter. Big deal.

Comment: You sir my hero <3

Answer (score 0):

This program will cause segmentation fault due to the fact that the temp function is taking h as a reference to pointer.

Change the signature of temp function to `void temp(Node* &h, int val)` and it will work.

The insert function allocates memory for h but the temp function is passing a temporary variable internally created by the compiler to the insert function